# How to update selenium-server-standalone to specific version for protractor and node-js?

Tags: visual-studio-code, protractor, node-modules, cucumber-serenity, serenity-js

**How to update selenium-server-standalone to specific version ?**

> As in my project I want version **3.0.1** but when I ran

```
webdriver-manager update
```

It downloads "**3.141.59**" version which is not compatible
 for my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can update selenium-server-standalone jar in two ways** :

1. Update to **latest** version :

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --standalone
> ```

2.a. Update to **Specific** version **globally** :

Globally means at : **user's AppData** location

```
"C:\Users\pritam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium"
```

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone "specific_version"
> ```

Example :

> ```
>  webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
> ```

2.b. Update to **Specific** version for specific **project** :

> ```
>  node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone "specific version"
> ```

Example :

> ```
>  node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.standalone 3.0.1
> ```